# Rails console includes differently than model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include

tl;dr: `include MyModule` brings `MyModule`'s functions into scope when run in rails console, but not when in a rails model. I don't understand and would like to be able to access these functions in my model.

I have this file `lib/zip_validator.rb`, which I would like to use to validate user input for my `User` model.

```
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
  def validates_zip(*attr_names)
    validates_with ZipValidator, _merge_attributes( attr_names )
  end
end

class ZipValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each( record, attr_name, value )
    unless is_legitimate_zipcode( self.zip )
      record.errors.add( attr_name, :zip, options.merge( value: value ))
    end
  end
end
```

In rails console, I can do

```
irb(main):005:0> include ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
=> Object
irb(main):006:0> validates_zip
NoMethodError: undefined method `validates_with' for main:Object
        from /home/bistenes/Programming/myapp/lib/zip_validator.rb:3:in `validates_zip'
        from (irb):6
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Look! Clearly it found `validates_zip`, because it's complaining about a call within that method. Maybe that complaint will go away when I actually try and call it from the model where it's going to be used, `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :zip, :email, :password, 
        :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmed_at

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :zip
  validates_zip :zip
```

When I attempt to start the server (Thin), it errors out with:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `validates_zip' for #<Class:0x00000003e03f28> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/bistenes/Programming/myapp/app/models/user.rb:38:in `<class:User>'
```

What in the world is going on? Why does the server fail to find a function that the console found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
module M
  def m
  end
end

class C
  include M
end
```

Given that, you can say `C.new.m` without complaint but you can't `C.m`. So what's going on here? When you say `include M`, the methods in `M` will be added to `C` as *instance* methods but if you wanted to say:

```
class C
  include M
  m
end
```

then `m` would have to be a *class* method since `self` when you call `m` here is the class itself. You can do this using the `included` hook in the module:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_exec do
      def m
      end
    end
  end
end
class C
  include M
  m # This works now
end
```

In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_exec do
      def self.validates_zip(*attr_names)
        validates_with ZipValidator, _merge_attributes( attr_names )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now your `User` will have a `validates_zip` class method that you can call in the desired context.